# Sort composed structs using qsort()

Tags: c, posix, qsort

I have the following structs. A `tDiscountsShop` contains, let's say 5 `tDiscount` structs.

```
#define MAXDISCOUNTS 50

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} bool;

    typedef struct {

        int dni;
        float discount;
        bool changed;

    } tDiscount;

    typedef struct {

        tDiscount discounts[MAXDISCOUNTS];
        int numDiscounts;

    } tDiscountsShop;
```

I would like to sort by `dni` using `qsort`. I'm trying using the following code:

```
int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
      tDiscount *e1 = (tDiscount *)s1;
      tDiscount *e2 = (tDiscount *)s2;

      return e1->dni - e2->dni;
}


qsort (discountsShop->discounts, discountsShop->numDiscounts, sizeof(discountsShop->discounts), compare);
```

I'll appreciate if I could have an explanation of what I'm doing wrong and how I could solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: It doesn't sort. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You are passing the size of the whole array instead of the size of each element.

Comment: Other issue: `e1->dni - e2->dni` can overflow.  Use `(e1->dni > e2->dni) - (e1->dni < e2->dni)`.  That works for all pairs of `int`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
sizeof(discountsShop->discounts)
```

gives you the **size of the whole array**.

What you need/want is the **size of one element**.

To get this do

```
sizeof(*discountsShop->discounts)
```

or

```
sizeof(discountsShop->discounts[0])
```

From [`qsort()`'s documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html):

> ```
> void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
>   int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
> ```
>
> [...]
>   The size of each object, in bytes, is specified by the *width* argument.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the size of the whole array instead of the size of each element.

```
sizeof(discountsShop->discounts)
```

should be

```
sizeof(discountsShop->discounts[0])
```

Comment: Anwsered while the answer from @alk had been wiped so not seen.

Comment: ... "*wiped*" because it was embarrassing wrong ... :} Lucky me we have an initial grace period. ;-)